# Creating button methods for a SUPER TIC TAC TOE game

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a Super Tac Toe game (its basically a 3x3 grid of tic tac toe boards)

where the board consists of a 3x3 block of buttons with the following click method

```
    private void buttonI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(jar == true)
    {
        buttonI.Text = "X";
    }
    if(jar == false)
    {
        buttonI.text = "O";
    }
    jar = !(jar)
}
```

where jar is a boolean variable that is used to keep track of each player's turn. I used a Python script to mass produce the code for `1 <= I <= 81` but... only my buttons 1-9 have correct functionality. These buttons were manually built using the Visual Studio IDE (I just double clicked them to create the button click method) but I see absolutely no difference in syntax between those buttons and the buttons that I massproduced code for.

Some help and a clear explanation would be awesome!

Comment: My guess is that you didn't actually wire up the code to the buttons themselves.  I find the easiest way to generate the wiring is to double click on the button in the IDE and let VS create the connection for you.

Comment: So how exactly does this wiring work? Is there a way to do it without actually double clicking all the buttons?

Comment: Sure, you have to attach your method to your event, something alongs the lines of `button1.Clicked += YourMethodName;`. Just take a look at the designer.cs class and you'll see how VS wire them up.

Comment: what would the argument of the methods be? Would it be the name of said button, and what would the argument for "actionEvent" be?

Comment: How do i find the designer.cs class?

Comment: Disregard that last comment, I can't seem to find the code for the wiring in the designer class. Where exactly do I need to look?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid "mass produced code"... If later you need to change the functionality, you would have to change it for 81 methods.  That's not maintainable.

**So, what to do?**

First of all, I wouldn't even manually drop each button into window.  I would have my code add each button for me.  Now, you didn't say if you were doing `WinForms` or `WPF`.  So I'll assume `WPF` because it's newer and I think far better.

**Programmatically adding Buttons**

Create a `Window` with a `Grid` named `gMain`.  Then tie to the window's `Initialize` event:

```
private void handleWindowInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Add 3 rows and 3 columns.
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    gMain.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    gMain.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
  }

  // Add button to each cell.
  for(int row=0; row<3; row++)
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
      createButton(row, column);
}
```

So now that we have setup `gMain`, lets look at the method `createButton()`.

**Building the Button**

```
private void createButton(int row, int column)
{
  var button = new Button();

  // Add to gMain
  gMain.Children.Add(button);

  // Place the button in the correct cell.
  Grid.SetRow(button, row);
  Grid.SetColumn(button, column);

  // Tie to the click event.
  button.Click += handleButtonClick;
}
```

Simple enough?  We just create a `Button`, add it to `gMain`, put in the correct cell, and then tie to the `Click` event.  Now lets look at the event handler.

**Event Handler**

```
void handleButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var button = (Button)sender;
  int row = Grid.GetRow(button);
  int column = Grid.GetColumn(button);

  // Do what ever you would like to do...
}
```

Notice that we are able to tell the column and row... from this you should be able to do whatever logic you need.  This is great because then you don't need a bunch of different methods.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.. ok. Basic rule #1: You're OBJECT ORIENTED. not MODULAR. Why duplicate the function?

Instead, you could SET an ID for the button, and have the same onClick event for all buttons

Define 9 buttons, each button with an id 0..8
So, each button will invoke

```
private void anyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // sender is your button! you can use it's .id or anything alike
    if(jar == true)
    {
        buttonI.Text = "X";
    }
    if(jar == false)
    {
        buttonI.text = "O";
    }
    jar = !(jar)
}
```

Comment: so I have to make 81 lines of private void button_kClick(etc...) { anyButton_Click(sender, e); }?

Comment: No, only one! Make all of the buttons go to the same onClick method. You can easily identify which button was tapped using the ID parameter of the button (or name, or what ever)

Comment: Can you explain this further? Is the method you have given, exactly as it is capable of working all the buttons or is there more to be done here?